# Android studio can't install new packges

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Arch linux and have installed Android studio by yay.However, when I try to use it to install SDK, NDK and lollipop, my PC suddenly freeze, I initially thought the problem might be related my swap space, so I deactivated it, but there was no difference in the situation. I also attempted to limit amount of RAM used by Android, but didn't help. I don't believe purchasing more ram solve would necessary solve the issue, because now I have 8gb memory.

install NDK and lollipop 5.0